# I got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, installation

I'm very new in coding. I know this is a very common question and I tried different solutions but I still cannot solve the problem.
I'm using pycharm (python38 w/ anaconda) to parse a webpage.
I checked in project interpreter and I have got pip and beautifulSoup4 installed, although pip doesn't work neather in cmd or in console (both pip and pip3).

There must have made some stupid error somewhere I cannot recognize.

Thank you for your help.

```js
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os

def make_soup(url):
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
    return soupdata
```

Comment: Are you running the code through PyCharm by executing a run configuration in your project?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the code through PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

If pip and pip3 doesn't work in cmd, you should check is python added to a path.

Edit:

Go to file manager right-click My Computer --> Properties --> Advanced System Settings --> Environment variables --> Path and check is python there.

Comment: Can you please detail a little bit more? Thanks

Comment: Ok, there wasn't a path. I added it but it still says invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get it to work using the interpreter settings method. I ran the following commands in the terminal to get it to work. I suspect that it has something to do with running the virtual environment.

python3 -m pip install bs4